# Removing date from select options once expired

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a basic select field form which users can select a date for a course they want more information on. These dates are manually added and do not populate from a database etc.

Once selected I have a script which dynamically uses this selected date to populate a cf7 enquiry form so I know the course title and interested course date.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to remove dates within the select fields that have expired and have this updated daily to ensure no old course dates appear.

Many thanks in advance.

```js
if (jQuery(".booking-date select").length) {
  var options = jQuery(".booking-date select > option").clone();
  jQuery('select.wpcf7-select[name="coursedates"]').empty().append(options);
  // Add on change Function
  jQuery('.booking-date select').on('change', function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).prop('selectedIndex');
    jQuery('select.wpcf7-select[name="coursedates"]').prop('selectedIndex', val);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Course Dates: </strong>
<div class="booking-date">
  <select class="coursedates">
    <option>17 December - 20 December 2019</option>
    <option>13 July - 17 July 2020</option>
    <option>14 December - 18 December 2020</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need some kind of "machine-readable" date format in your select options ("yyyy-mm-dd" or similar), otherwise it will be difficult to construct a meaningful filter mechanism.

Comment: So if for example I change the select option dates to a readable format ("yyyy"mm"dd") how can I then produce the outcome I need? Plus, is there a way i can show the machine rebate date in a more aesthetic way for the user?

Comment: `option`s can have a value that differs from the text eg. `<option value="2020-02-06">6th February 2020</option>`

Comment: So could anyone help me come up with something to target the select values and hide them once they have expired?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value containing a standard date format to your options would allow you to easily compare Date objects.

```js
$('.coursedates option').each(function() {
  var courseEndDate = new Date($(this).val());
  var dateNow = new Date();
  
  if (dateNow > courseEndDate) {
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('Removing ' + $(this).text() + '. Course has ended.');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="coursedates">
  <option value="2019-12-20">17 December - 20 December 2019</option>
  <option value="2020-07-17">13 July - 17 July 2020</option>
  <option value="2020-12-18">14 December - 18 December 2020</option>
</select>
```

Comment: – Thank you very much! I have added the jQuery to my site and added option values but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems the jQuery conflicts with the other snippet which dynamically populates the cf7 form. Any reason why they would conflict?

Comment: What do you mean by "conflicts with"?

Comment: It just stops working. If i use your snippet alone it works perfectly in jsfiddle but as soon as it sits with the original snippet on the website it doesn't hide the date anymore.

Comment: You would need to make sure that this snippet runs after your other snippet has completed manipulating the inputs

Comment: I've set it up as follows:

Comment: <script>
*original snippet*
</script>
<script>
*your snippet*
</script>

Comment: Your snippet is using `jQuery` rather than `$`. Have you changed `$` to `jQuery` when adding my snippet?

Comment: No i haven't. do i just change any instance of $ to say jQuery?

Comment: Yes. If that doesn't work you will have to create a reproducible example on JSFiddle/CodePen etc. Otherwise I'm just guessing.

Comment: Its set up in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/24m0cq5b/#&togetherjs=7cDV098hfn

the old date is disappearing but when the user selects a date it doesn't auto update the form date selection as you'll see in the fiddle